# My javascript to jQuery translation has a bug

Tags: javascript, jquery

My guess is that this javascript just finds the div called `divid` and then uses it with the `sendit` function.

```
var somevalue = 19; 
if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
    thediv = window["divid"]; 
} else { 
    thediv = document["divid"];
}
thediv.sendit(somevalue);
```

I would imagine in jQuery it would look something as simple as this:

```
var somevalue = 19;
$('divid').sendit(somevalue);
```

But it's not working!! What could I be missing?

I should say that it's in the middle of other javascript code, could that be a problem?

Comment: What's `sendit`?  New one to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to get the actual DOM object (not the JQuery collection) to access the function that you set on it.

```
$('divid').get(0).sendit(somevalue);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there is an element with ID 'divid' you need to use the ID selector #

```
var somevalue = 19;
$('#divid').sendit(somevalue);
```

That may not be the whole answer as it's unclear where `sendit` is defined.